# Using XQuery to count nodes with a certain criteria

Tags: selection, xquery

I am trying to return a count of all audio books and print books by the publisher, "Seagypsy Publishing". A sample of my XML is as follows:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>Tales of The Sea</title>
        <publisher>Seagypsy Publishing</publisher>
        <type>print</type>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Storm Shanties</title>
        <publisher>Seagypsy Publishing</publisher>
        <type>audio</type>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Fabulous Sea Monsters</title>
        <publisher>Seagypsy Publishing</publisher>
        <type>audio</type>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Pirates!</title>
        <publisher>Hobbes</publisher>
        <type>audio</type>
    </book>
</books>
```

This is the XQuery I have, and although it correctly returns a count of the audio and print books, it doesn't return only the ones by Seagypsy Publishing. How can I correct this? Would it be better to use map somehow?

```
xquery version "3.0";

for $books in doc("books.xml")/books
let $audio_count := count($books/book[type = 'audio'] 
    and $books/book[publisher = 'Seagypsy Publishing'])
let $print_count := count($books/book[type = 'print'] 
    and $books/book[publisher = 'Seagypsy Publishing'])
return 
    <seagypsy_count>
        <audio_books>{$audio_count}</audio_books>
        <print_books>{$print_count}</print_books>
    </seagypsy_count>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count `book` elements that have both child `type = 'audio'` and child `publisher = 'Seagypsy Publishing'` in the same parent :

```
.....
let $audio_count := count($books/book[type = 'audio' and publisher = 'Seagypsy Publishing'])
let $print_count := count($books/book[type = 'print' and publisher = 'Seagypsy Publishing'])
.....
```